# Simple SELECT(*) queries very slow in Apache Ignite

Tags: sql, performance, key-value, ignite, in-memory-database

I'm prototyping Apache Ignite for use in a new product. I need to store a very wide matrix in memory and access various random rows and columns. The matrix has 50,000 columns and potentially millions of rows. The matrix will essentially be read-only so we don't worry about write speeds.

We do not ever need to order the results. The client application will request specific rows by the primary key and perhaps certain columns, and occasionally the entire row(s).

I loaded the data into Apache Ignite into a SQL table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myMatrix
name CHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
col1 INT,
col2 INT,
col3 INT,
...
col50000 INT
```

I've also indexed the 'name' column

```
CREATE INDEX name_index ON myMatrix(name)
```

However, when I try to simply select one row, it takes over 10 seconds to return the result. We need much much faster response times - the client will expect a set of rows (could be hundreds or thousands) and columns (up to all the columns) in less than a second.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyignite
from pyignite import Client
import time

client = Client()

client.connect('127.0.0.1', 10800)

now = time.time()
result = client.sql('SELECT * FROM full_test_table WHERE      name=\'F1S4_160106_058_G01\'')
print('Got Result in')
print(time.time() - now)
```

Why is this so painfully slow? I was hoping holding the entire table in memory would give faster results. Is it just the width of the table that's causing issues?

The database is running on an r4.8xlarge instance, with 32 cores and 244GB of memory.

Comment: Did you verify the index usage with a query plan? Also it looks a bit wierd you need to make a extra index on name as It already has a primary key

Comment: I didn't need to, but at the time I wasn't sure if Ignite generated indexes with the primary key.

It looks like the primary key index is being used:

    __Z0."440590" AS __C0_50274,
    __Z0."100131879" AS __C0_50275,
    __Z0."79699" AS __C0_50276,
    __Z0."7791" AS __C0_50277,
    __Z0."23140" AS __C0_50278,
    __Z0."26009" AS __C0_50279,
    __Z0."259265" AS __C0_50280,
    __Z0."150478" AS __C0_50281
     FROM PUBLIC.FULL_TEST_TABLE __Z0
    /* PUBLIC."_key_PK_proxy": NAME = 'F1S4_160106_058_G01' */
    WHERE __Z0.NAME = 'F1S4_160106_058_G01'

Comment: If that is the case i would suggest looking into a more mature database

Comment: Any recommendations?

Comment: MySQL, MariaDB or PostgreSQL all opensource and free databases

Comment: @RaymondNijland they are not distributed, though.

Comment: Oh you mean you need a mature embedded database which i assume you mean with distributed?  Well SQLite?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Distributed means distributing data over different nodes on different machines.

Comment: Seams i totally misinterpret the meaning of distributed i think i needed coffee badly at that time of writing @alamar he is wrong as MySQL/MariaDB supports [clustering](https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/) which does that thing..

Comment: *"MySQL Cluster is the distributed database combining linear scalability and high availability. It provides in-memory real-time access with transactional consistency across partitioned and distributed datasets. It is designed for mission critical applications.

MySQL Cluster has replication between clusters across multiple geographical sites built-in. A shared nothing architecture with data locality awareness make it the perfect choice for running on commodity hardware and in globally distributed cloud infrastructure.."*

Comment: For PostreSQL clustering  see [Replication, Clustering, and Connection Pooling](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried running an example very similar to yours, and it turns out that Ignite's SQL parser (based on H2 SQL parser) has quadratic performance compexity of number of response columns. This means it is totally unfeasible having 50,000 columns in a table in Ignite, or anything larger than few dozens for that matter. I will try to file an issue against H2 bug tracker.

Previous answer:

> Do you have persistence, or is everything in the RAM? I just can't see why it would take so long. Maybe there's some inlining problem - have you tried `CREATE INDEX name_index ON myMatrix(name) INLINE_SIZE 25`?
>
> I second that having 50,000 columns is not optimal. Better use an array.

Comment: The only issue with using an array is that we need to fetch the whole array before getting individual values from it. Often we will only be interested in a small subset of the array.

Comment: Internally Ignite will have to deserialize whole object anyway when you access it. Network transfer of array will likely be more efficient than transferring individual columns.

Comment: So, in that case shouldn't storing it in a SQL table be the same as storing arrays? SQL provides more ease of use and readability.

Comment: Nope, SQL also has a lot of metadata/processing for every column, which may turn out to be very slow.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. That's interesting because Ignite and Casandra advertise themselves for 'scaling to billions of rows and millions of columns' when in reality it struggles with thousands of rows and tens of thousands of columns...

Comment: I'm not really sure that Ignite advertises millions of columns anywhere, but if it does, I'm adamant it should be amended. Any links?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer, but I saw your previous question, and now I see you're using pandas. What if you just pickle your matrix (NumPy/pandas `Array`, I suppose) and put it in Ignite cache as a `ByteArrayObject`, and then unpickle it to `pandas.Array` before use? Will it solve your question in general?

Here's a little remark, if it will. `ByteArrayObject` is very slow in the current release, but I have already made the improvements, and fixes are waiting to be included in the next versions. Write me if you need them packaged.

There is also [Apache Ignite Users](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/) mailing list. You can subscribe and discuss your task there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@alamar's analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56769246/2998), if you really can't move away from having thousands of columns, I'd recommend you use the k-v API: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/python-thin-client-key-value

Having said that, *not* having 50,000 columns in a cache/table would be a better solution.